# How to improve performance in SQL Server table with varbinary column?

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, query-performance, varbinary, varbinarymax

I have a table in my database that we use as a filestore, the file itself is stored in a varbinary(MAX) column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FILE_TABLE](
    [FILE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HTML_FILE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [XML_FILE] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [FILE_EXTENSION] [nvarchar](50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FILE_TABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FILE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

We also created the following non-clustered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20180220-000116] ON [dbo].[FILE_TABLE]
(
    [FILE_ID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [XML_FILE]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This table has semantics and freetext enabled to run a keyword search against the documents. When we run a simple freetext query, the performance is very slow. The table has 810 records only and **it takes 30 seconds to return 713 rows**. How could we improve the performance of this table or query?

```
SELECT * FROM FILE_TABLE WHERE freetext(XML_FILE,'lights')
```

Comment: Don't do a SELECT * ... that requires pulling the entire contents of the varbinary field(s), which can be huge and consume a ton of bandwidth. Try comparing with just a SELECT FILE_ID FROM FILE_TABLE and see if that works faster for you. You can then just pull back the full file contents for those items the user is actually interested in.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was helpful and allowed us to pay attention to the way we are querying the table